# adding a question mark to the url in url rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi everybody i am trying to append a question mark at the end of my file name in url rewrite, after which will be my url parameters, like example the expected url is like:

```
http://localhost/project/pass/?something@gmail.com-3861
```

and the rule that i am using is below:

```
RewriteRule ^pass/?(\w.+)-(\w.+)$   view/pass.php?useremail=$1&actcode=$2 [L]
```

but the `?` is not working as i assuming it to be a reserved keyword. If i use some other things like `-` then they work

Can anyone tell me solution to that so that i can use `?` in my url rewrite?

Comment: RewriteRule does not accept query

Comment: @splash58, so what i am trying to do is impossible to do? If yes then i will have to adjust with `-` instead of `/?`

Comment: Possible - i write in  my answer. Let's understand why it doesn't work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteRule does not accept query. Use RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\w.+)-(\w.+) 
RewriteRule ^pass/$   view/pass.php?useremail=%1&actcode=%2 [L]
```

Comment: your code does not show 404 error but it does not detect the url parameters. Do i need to replace `QUERY_STRING` with some other user defined value of mine?

Comment: I just now try `example.com/pass/?a=b` and receive `_GET["a"] b`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use reserved characters without theirs function (`?` stands for "zero times or once"), add backslash `\` before them.

Comment: tried this one `RewriteRule ^passreset/\?(\w.+)-(\w.+)$   view/passreset.php?useremail=$1&actcode=$2 [L]` but did not work for me